Contour integral of complex generalized function
I'm reading a derivation of the Green function for the hyperbolic PDE and got to the point where I need to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\omega t}(\frac{1}{\omega-kc-i0}-\frac{1}{\omega+kc-i0})d\omega$$ First thing that is done is we look at two cases: $t>0$ and $t<0$.
For each we use the following contour:
Now it says that in the first case $t>0$ the integral is:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\omega t}(\frac{1}{\omega-kc-i0}-\frac{1}{\omega+kc-i0})d\omega=2\pi i(e^{itkc}-e^{-itkc})$$
and that for the second case $t<0$ it is zero. So the full answer should be:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\omega t}(\frac{1}{\omega-kc-i0}-\frac{1}{\omega+kc-i0})d\omega=\theta(t)2\pi i(e^{itkc}-e^{-itkc})$$
How do you get to this answer? I'm a bit rusty on complex integration but it doesn't make sense to me that in the second case the integral should be zero. I think It should be: $$-\pi i (e^{itkc}-e^{-itkc})$$
Can you show me how is that integral evaluated?

Is it because we have $i0$ in the denominator and we dont exclude the integrals in the small semicirles around the poles?

I think that $i0$ should be interpreted as $i\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0,$ and letting $\epsilon\to0$ in the end.

The notation $-i0$ actually means $-i\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ where we let $\epsilon\to0$ in the end.
Case $t>0$:
The integral for just the first term is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i\omega t} \frac{1}{\omega-kc-i\epsilon} \, d\omega.
$$
The pole is located just above the real axis, so a standard D-formed contour in the upper half-plane encloses the pole. Thus the value is $2\pi i \, e^{ikct}.$
Likewise for the second term.
Case $t<0$: In this case we must take a contour in the lower half-plane. But the poles are still located just above the real axis, i.e. outside of the contour. Therefore the value is $0.$
